# Why is NYS supplemental rate so high?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, withholding, new-york, bonus

For 2019 the NYS suplemental withholding rate was [9.62%](https://taxnews.ey.com/news/2019-0064-state-supplemental-income-tax-withholding-rates-for-2019).  However the maximum tax bracket in NYS is [8.82%](https://www.tax-brackets.org/newyorktaxtable) for 2019.  This means that even for the highest earners the withholding will be too much and they will be due a refund at tax filing.

Is there any reason for this? Other than NYS wanting to take advantage of an interest free loan from its citizens?